# problem in creating textview programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm try to create programmatically textView for a project. My problem is that I don't now how to set up the position of the textview on the screen.

I tried with the code below but instead of moving the textview it moves all the margin. The code is this:

```
  constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint);

        TextView valueTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        valueTV.setText("TEST");
        valueTV.setTextColor(R.color.black);
        valueTV.setId(id);
        valueTV.setHeight(50);
        valueTV.setWidth(50);

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
        constraintLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
        constraintLayout.addView(valueTV);
```

the code is inside the oncreate. Thanks for help

Comment: can you provide a picture of your desired output ?

Comment: ConstraintLayout is best used via the editor where you can design your layouts and see everything relatively laid out. Why are you adding views programmatically? What is your desired goal? There's probably a better way.

Comment: I have to set the textview in center of the screen but I don't know how I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
valueTV.setText("TEST");
valueTV.setTextColor(R.color.black);
valueTV.setId(id);
valueTV.setHeight(50);
valueTV.setWidth(100);
constraintLayout.addView(valueTV);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) valueTV.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.rightToRight = constraintLayout.getId();
layoutParams.topToTop = constraintLayout.getId();
layoutParams.bottomToBottom = constraintLayout.getId();
layoutParams.leftToLeft = constraintLayout.getId();
valueTV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```